# To modify SecurityContext only for Current request

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, spring-session

I am using Spring Boot+spring session data rediss
My scenario is UserA has logged in and JSESSIONID is created for UserA, now he issues a token which will be sent to some machine and is valid for few minutes to work on his behalf.
Issue is if accidently some client passes both Cookie and token then I want to give preference to **TOKEN** rather than **JSESSIONID** is it possible in **Spring Session**.
I cannot invalidate the cookie session as it will logout the UserA which is not desired.

So, I want to tell spring wether to use existing session or create a new one based on some condition and want to give preference to **TOKEN**. And to create a completely new session without invalidating Cookie session.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the official documentation.

From this

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession 
public class Config {

        @Bean
        public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
                return new LettuceConnectionFactory(); 
        }
}
```

It's done by default.

`The @EnableRedisHttpSession annotation creates a Spring Bean with the name of springSessionRepositoryFilter that implements Filter. The filter is what is in charge of replacing the HttpSession implementation to be backed by Spring Session. In this instance Spring Session is backed by Redis.`

`We create a RedisConnectionFactory that connects Spring Session to the Redis Server. We configure the connection to connect to localhost on the default port (6379) For more information on configuring Spring Data Redis, refer to the reference documentation.`

`The DelegatingFilterProxy will look up a Bean by the name of springSessionRepositoryFilter and cast it to a Filter. For every request that DelegatingFilterProxy is invoked, the springSessionRepositoryFilter will be invoked.`

So, what you have to do, it's avoid the Spring Configuration, or looking for if you want modify this default behavior somehow to create your own DelegatingFilterProxy implementation and setup it in your ServletContext Filter chain.

Comment: I am able to achieve this by providing my own implementation of HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository and then setting http.securityContext().securityContextRepository(new CustomHttpSessionSecurityContextRepository());

So , I am implementing my own SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper in which I am not saving the context and hence it is not changed in the session.